# Linecast losing its target randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using `Physics.Linecast` in my `Update()` method to determine the distance to the next way point in a racing game. The code casts a line from the players transform position, and targets the nearest point on the mesh of the next way point (using `ClosestPointOnBounds`).

This works perfectly for the first two way points, however at some point between the 2nd and 3rd one the functionality ceases, (null reference? but....how!?).

This has got me completely stumped. The line cast correctly targets way point 3 for a while before randomly 'losing sight' of it...I have no idea why, especially as it does work for a while!

I've made my debug draw lines last for 5 seconds after they're cast. So, in the image below you'll see:

1. lines cast towards waypoint 2 successfully
2. lines beginning to be cast towards waypoint 3 successfully
3. suddenly lines no longer being cast towards waypoint 3

[image]

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 raycastStart = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1, transform.position.z);            

            // NOTE: nextWayPoint is a gameObject, populated by referencing the relevant index position in the waypoints array

        if (nextWayPoint != null)
        {
            // Cast a ray from the player's position towards the mesh collider of the next waypoint...
            RaycastHit hit;
            Physics.Linecast(raycastStart, nextWayPoint.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().ClosestPointOnBounds(transform.position) - transform.position, out hit, waypointsLayer);               

            // Render this line so we can see it...
            Debug.DrawLine(raycastStart, hit.point, Color.red, 5f);

            // Populate the distance variable with the length of the ray
            disToNextWayPoint = hit.distance;
        }
```

Any ideas, thoughts or general nudges in the right direction would certainly save me from insanity at this point!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It may helpful if you posted a code snippet of the problem you are having. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Matt :) I've edited my op to include the code in question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you subtracting your position from the nextWayPoint position?  As I understand it, LineCast is expecting Vector3 end to not be relative to the start position.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, but it seems to give a more accurate length to the Linecast by having it in there. I've tried taking this subtraction out but it causes the Linecast to target 0,0,0 immediately (the issue that crops up above)

Comment: I assume that nextWayPoint will be set to null some time between 2 and 3 if I understand you correctly. Is there any code that is setting/messing with that variable?

Comment: Yeah it seems that is what's happening but I can't figure out why. The only thing that changes the next waypoint is when you go through the waypoint trigger itself, which increments a float (the float is then used to point at the waypoint array index). I'm wondering if the bounding box of the waypoint object has anything to do with it...

Comment: have you added a Debug.Log to where the float is incremented to see if the problem is related to the trigger?

Comment: I've given up with it now, I don't have enough hair to spare to carry on trying to resolve it :D

I went with a different solution in the end, simply using a mixture of `Vector3.Distance` and several tactfully placed box colliders aligned with the waypoints themselves helped me to achieve what I wanted to.

Appreciate all the comments either way folks, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get distance between 2 points - best way it's use `Vector3.Distance` (I seen your comment, know than you found this case).

As for

> (null reference? but....how!?).

physics cast functions can return null hit if start point of cast was in collider - check your case for this.